# Alt-Gr on PC keyboard is mapped to Command; can I map it to Alt?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have just installed a PC keyboard on my Mac Mini, everything is looking good, I swapped the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd> so that it's more natural for a Mac keyboard but I just can't get used to <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>.

I need to use some <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + keys to get some specific keys on a non English keyboard.  While this works as expected on a PC, e.g. <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> to get the @ sign on the PC keybaord connected to the Mac then the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> acts like a <kbd>Command</kbd> key

Hence, to get an @ sign I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> and not <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>  — thus, can I remap <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

I keep pressing the wrong key. I have to switch between Mac and PC keyboards.

Comment: I have the same problem and didn't find the answer (also the below though)

Answer (score 4):

Get [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) or [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/)

These keys are normally termed as Modifier Keys. Mac OSX does allow some modifications , to swap functionality etc, but does not allow to combine the functionality. You'll need to get one of the above add-ons to get it done.

Just for reference, will attach a screenshot of the default OSX key modifier functionality.
[image: Mac OSX Modifier Keys]

Comment: For macOS Sierra, there's a new tool for solving that problem: https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md